# Taking in a File as a parameter

Tags: java

```
public fillVal(File s) throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(s);

    while(kb.hasNextDouble()){
        //etc...

    }
```

So say my file name is "file1.txt". When I go to enter that text ("file1.txt") int BlueJ's "create object tab" I get something that says incompatible types. I have the txt file in the file with the class. Is this not a valid way to take in a file and take values from it? Let me know if this is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take an object as a parameter, you need to pass in an instance of that object.

Since all you want to do is pass in the file name, then your signature is incorrect; change that to accept `String` instead.

```
public void fillVal(String fileName) {
    try {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while(kb.hasNextDouble()) {
           // code
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid filename!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Oh, and don't forget the return type.  Since it doesn't *look* like you're doing anything with the results, you can declare it to return `void`.

Comment: Ok that looks good. I am curious though what is the process for actually passing a file in as a parameter? Is .txt not considered a file?

Comment: Well...again, you'd have to create an instance of a `File` object and pass that around.  `String` is an object too, but it's more readily accessible than other objects.  What we're doing is really the same thing, it's just that in the snippet I've provided, I'm using a different object.  Passing in the path or the file name is perfectly acceptable to create the object, as it takes away the burden of instantiating an object you're only ever going to use once, and places it into the simplest place possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it needs a file object?

```
new java.io.File("file1.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following method:

```
public void fillVal(File s) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(s);

    while (kb.hasNextDouble()){
        System.out.println("The next double is: " + kb.nextDouble());
    }
}
```

You would call it from some main method by creating an instance of the class containing the fillVal(File) method, and calling it as done below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    . . .

    try {
        [name of instance].fillVal(new File("README.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This assumes that the file README.txt is in the root directory of your BlueJ project.  Which is also where the class files will be placed.

File
    public File(String pathname)

Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract pathname.

Parameters:
pathname - A pathname string

Throws:
NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null